# As i ahve not kept any file in resource folder why we need to map to resource folder to load all static Resource?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, xml-configuration

[its contains a tag mvc:resource tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqS7k.png)I am developing a spring mvc application in which iam using xml based configuration.I want to load my static resource.To do this i am using a tag `<mvc:resources location="/assets/" mapping="/resources/**"/>.`

All my static resources is present in assets folder so i am giving the loaction. but in mapping why it is `mapping="/resources/**"`? I have not kept anything in resource folder and what does ** represents?

Can anyone clear all my doubts here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<mvc:resources location="/assets/" mapping="/assets/**"/>
```

Update `mapping="/assets/**"`, It will work fine. In Mapping attribute you should keep the matching url pattern to access the assets folder.

** :- Means multiple directories in this path or Zero directories after assets directory.

Take an example:-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${contextRoot}/assets/js/login.js"></script>
```

You want to add a java script file in your page. To add this js file, the server request become : http://localhost:8090/Aashayein/assets/js/login.js . As you are using spring-mvc so the request goes through dispatcher servlet(front controller). For this request Uri there is no corresponding handler marked (@RequestMapping("/assets/js/login.js")), so it results 404 error. So you have to tell spring that if any request comes with uri pattern "/assets/**" then directly looks to the assets folder present in the webapp directory. To do so in xml we have to write:-

```
<mvc:resources location="/assets/" mapping="/assets/**"/>
```

In annotation:-

```
/*
 * Any request with url mapping /assets/** will directly look for /assets
 * folder.
*/
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

   registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/**").addResourceLocations("/assets/");
}
```